checking the presence of any of the character from a certain set of characters in an Excel cell, and returning values accordingly
I have a data set in which there are several cells that should contain numbers but are formatted as text.
What I am trying to do is enter a formula that checks for the presence of any of the following characters (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), and if found returns the value in the cell as a NUMBERVALUE, otherwise returns the value of the cell as it is.
I have tried with a COUNTIF like this: =IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*0123456789*"),NUMBERVALUE(A1),A1), however it returns the value of the cell as it is whether the cell contains one of the characters from 0 to 9 or not.
What could be the solution for this?

The best way I can come up with is IF(NOT(ISERR(VALUE(A1)), VALUE(A1), A1). This tests if a string value can be converted to a legal number (and also works on something that is truly a number).

@Moataz Goubarah Can the cell being checked contain letters and numbers? And what output do you expect if more than one number is found?

Please share some samples with expected output

Try:
=IFERROR(A1*1,A1)

A1*1 coerces a number in cell A1 formatted as text to display as a number (i.e., right aligned), so there's no  need to explicitly compare numerals to the value in the cell. If there are numbers and text or just text in the cell, then the result of the calculation will be an error and the value in cell A1 will display as is.

Many thanks. I tried the formula above and it worked. The result was exactly what I was trying to do. The formula returned the alphabet only and the mixed cells as is, and the digit-only cells that were stored as text were transformed into numbers.

@Moataz Goubarah That's great. Would you mind selecting this as the answer? Thank you.
